# Count New Lines in Text File

Tags: php, count, newline

I would like to count the number of shift+enters in a text file using PHP.

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean newline characters? For example:
This sentence\n
has three\n
lines to it.

Comment: You mean the `"\r"|"\n"|"\r\n"` newline?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you just mean `"\r\n"` (carriage-return + line feed) by this, the function [`substr_count`](https://www.php.net/substr_count) in conjunction with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) should do the trick.

For example:

```
$count = substr_count(file_get_contents($filename), "\r\n");
```

Comment: COunting just "\n" will support mac, linux and windows files which may not all use returns (\r)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this task by key-events.  I think php don't have any key event, so you can use any scripting language like java-script that have key events.