# How to count number of rows in CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv which includes a column allowing a multi-line string.

```
sku,name,description
123,"Product Name Here","Multi-line description
goes here.
Lots of multi-line content"
```

I am interested in counting the number of rows I have in my CSV. I have tried

```
 $num_rows = count(file($filename));
 var_dump($num_rows); //4 < WHAY too high
```

but this counts each line in the multi-line cell as well.

To get the actual number of lines I am currently using:

```
//get number of rows
$num_rows = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num_rows++;
}
var_dump($num_rows); //2 < The actual number of rows
```

I then do another `while` loop to process the CSV.

Is there a way to get the number of rows in a CSV without using the above while loop?

#### CSV

Here is a sample CSV. The number of lines I am looking for is `3` not `28`

```
sku, name, description
123, "Product name", "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Mauris pretium enim facilisis, tincidunt elit id, congue est.</p>

<p>Donec eu eros quis elit mattis dapibus.</p>

<p>Sed euismod augue nec metus accumsan, et ultricies elit mattis.</p>

<p>Vestibulum aliquet est sit amet neque congue lacinia.<br/>
Donec viverra augue quis orci interdum mattis.<br/>
Phasellus ullamcorper risus quis dolor tempus sagittis.</p>

<p>Integer vel augue iaculis turpis vestibulum commodo eu quis nunc.</p>"

456, "Another Product name", "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Mauris pretium enim facilisis, tincidunt elit id, congue est.</p>

<p>Donec eu eros quis elit mattis dapibus.</p>

<p>Sed euismod augue nec metus accumsan, et ultricies elit mattis.</p>

<p>Vestibulum aliquet est sit amet neque congue lacinia.<br/>
Donec viverra augue quis orci interdum mattis.<br/>
Phasellus ullamcorper risus quis dolor tempus sagittis.</p>

<p>Integer vel augue iaculis turpis vestibulum commodo eu quis nunc.</p>"
```

Comment: `$rows = count(explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('myCSVfile.csv')));` ?

Comment: @sandnig hope the newline will ever be \r\n ,)

Comment: No, there isn't any shortcut method, your while loop is the only method that will return a correct result

Comment: @sandnig And won't this have the same issue, counting linebreaks _inside_ cells which should not be counted?

Comment: @arkascha you are right,  my fault

Comment: I think the `fgetcsv()` approach is the way to go, since you simply do need knowledge about the csv format whilst parsing here. All other approaches will be much more complex, since you have to implement that knowledge.

Comment: @sandnig Nope, the multi-line column gets exploded as well and inflates the row count.

Comment: Since your row always starts with a number (id), why not use RegEx? Don't kill me for this, but here it goes: `preg_match_all('#\d+,#', $csv, $rows);` `$rows = count($rows[0]) +1;` - returns 3 on your example

Answer (score 0):

In PHP5 you have a very fast solution for small-medium sized files:

```
$fp = count(file('test.csv', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
```

source:  [How can I get the total number of rows in a CSV file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447329/how-can-i-get-the-total-number-of-rows-in-a-csv-file-with-php)

If file is huge, better use this scheme, like is said in post:

```
$c =0;
$fp = fopen("test.csv","r");
if($fp){
    while(!feof($fp)){
          $content = fgets($fp);
      if($content)    $c++;
    }
}
fclose($fp);
echo $c;
```

If you only want to count carriage returns (line breaks) try this:

```
$count = substr_count(file_get_contents($filename), "\r\n");
```

source: [Count New Lines in Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731838/count-new-lines-in-text-file)

Comment: This won't solve the issue addressed here: linebreaks inside csv cells which should not be counted

Comment: Hello, I think it will be easier if you use ";" as line separator (and encode comment fields). Then this will do the job   $count = substr_count(file_get_contents($filename), ";");

Comment: Still doesn't allow for the possibility of a `;` in the data itself

Comment: Could you post a link to a real example of csv file please?

Comment: The poster has given an example of a CSV file in their question

Comment: I mean the original file with line breaks.  His copy-pasted example is not valid for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If your description entries are always enclosed in quotes:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/(description|\")$/m", file_get_contents($filename), $matches);
```

now sizeof($matches[1]) contains number of rows in CSV